# undelete trigger error

Tags: apex, trigger, undelete

I need to delete some events and after undelete them. Now to do this i'm using two triggers, the first in after insert delete all the events if they are alldayevent,the second trigger undelet a list of events under certain conditions.

the second trigger is:

```
trigger eventundeleter on Event (after delete) {
if(checkRecursive2.runOnce()){
System.debug('partito');
List<Event> eventi=[select Id,Subject,Priorit_Alta__c,IsAllDayEvent,Whoid,ShowAs,ordinatozz__c,Description,WhatId,Location,
                                Ownerid,StartDateTime,EndDateTime,Ora_inizio__c,Ora_fine__c,IsReminderSet,ReminderDateTime,
                                 Undeleting__c
                   from Event
                   where  Undeleting__c=true  AND IsAllDayEvent=true
                   ORDER BY ordinatozz__c,StartDateTime ASC ALL ROWS];
System.debug('list to be undeleted: '+ eventi);
undelete eventi; 
}                        
}
```

Salesforce give me this error, but I don't understand why:

> eventundeleter: execution of AfterDelete caused by:
>   System.DmlException: Undelete failed. First exception on row 4 with id
>   00U58000003EfE5EAK; first error: SELF_REFERENCE_FROM_TRIGGER, Object
>   (id = 00U58000003EfE5) is currently in trigger eventundeleter,
>   therefore it cannot recursively undelete itself: []
>   Trigger.eventundeleter: line 11, column 1: []: Trigger.eventdeleter:
>   line 67, column 1

how can I fix it?

Comment: you can create future/queueable job to do it in different context

Comment: I did it , but now I have another requirement, I need to undelete the records following a precise sequence. Is it possible in salesforce?.
I explain better. The records have a number field "ordinato__c" and I have to recreate them from the Recycle Bin following an  ordinato__c ascendent sequence.

Comment: Hi, can you post this new part as a new question? SFSE doesn't really support major changes to the question, it doesn't work like a discussion based forum.

Comment: I solved the problem, I used the code below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You can definitely use a `@future` method for this.
- Your parameter will be a `Set<Id>` to specify which records need to be restored.
- When you re-query for the records, you can use an `ORDER BY` clause to specify which field to sort by (`ordinato__c`).
- You can make sure your query includes records in the Recycle Bin by adding the `ALL ROWS` clause.

So something like:

```
@future
public static void undeleteRecords(Set<Id> deletedIds)
{
    undelete [
        SELECT Id FROM MyObject
        WHERE Id IN :deletedIds
        ORDER BY Ordinato__c
        ALL ROWS
    ];
}
```